# Difficulty deleting music from music library on my iPhone

Tags: icloud, music

I'm having difficulty managing music in my iTunes library on my phone. I have old songs that I do not want anymore that are still showing up with the iCloud symbol (ready to download) in my library. Even going to settings to hide certain downloaded music, the songs I do not want still appear (just without the iCloud symbol) and cannot be deleted. I want to completely get rid of some songs. Help.

Comment: Please can you update your question with details of your device/OS level etc.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I went into **Settings** on my iPhone and to **Music**. Towards the bottom it says **Show All Music**. I just disabled that and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

At first, hide all iTunes Music tracks. Go to Settings > Music > Show All Music and turning it off.

Find the track you wish to delete and long-press the song cover and you'll be presented with options - one of which is to 'Delete from Library'. Tap on this option and you'll be asked to confirm the deletion. That's it.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem go to settings>music>show all music and slide the button over. Hope this helped!